# Configuring JNotify on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, jnotify

How to configure Jnotify on Mac OS X. i am using MyEclipse and latest version of Jnotify.
I am new to MAC OS and just added jnotify.jar in my lib path.
when i run my main class.

Following exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1754)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
at net.contentobjects.jnotify.macosx.JNotify_macosx.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding native library to the jar path.
expanding the jnotify.jar and adding native lib to it. its working fine now in myeclipse environment